# Recursively walk through an array/object with render functions with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, vue.js, vuejs2

An example of what I'm dealing with
https://codepen.io/wombsplitter/pen/KyWKod

My array structure is as follows

```
[{
 //obj 1
 link: [{
        //obj 2
        link: [{
              //obj 3
              }]
        }]
}]
```

The array can hold any number of elements at any "level". I want to recursively walk through the way and using a render functions, print them to the page while preserving their structure.

```
div.item
  div.info
  div.link
     div.info
     div.link
        div.info
        div.link
           div.info
           div.link
```

Any help, advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your console should show you the structure. You just want the values, if they're not Objects?

Comment: I should add that each object in each array will most likely hold properties, so I'm walking through each sub array, and printing said data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
renderFunction(h, arr) {
  return renderStructure(this.test, h)
}

// outside of your App object
function rendeStructure(test, h){
  return h('div', { class: 'link'}, test.map(t => {
    return h('div', {class: 'info'}, [t.name, renderStructure(t.links, h)]);
  }))
}
```

This does assume there are no cycles in your data.

Comment: I had to alter it a bit, but it seems to be doing the trick, thanks.

Comment: Cool. I haven't used Vue, so I made some assumptions on how things work

Answer (score 0):

You have an erorr in your code see below I'm calling arr.map you were calling this.test.map

```
    renderFunction(h, arr) {
      return h('div', { class: 'link'}, arr.map(t => {
        return h('div', t.name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy way, should be correct :

```
function recurse(obj){
   var html = ['<div class="info"></div>'];
   html.push('<div class="link">')
   if(!!obj.link) html.push(recurse(obj.link[0]));
   html.push('</div>')
   return html.join('')
}

document.getElementsByClassName('item')[0].innerHtml = recurse(obj[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, if you just want the values:

```js
function getVals(mixed){
  var r = [];
  function rec(mixed){
    var a;
    if(mixed instanceof Array){
      for(var i=0,l=mixed.length; i<l; i++){
        a = mixed[i];
        if(typeof a === 'object' && a !== null){
          return rec(a);
        }
        else{
          r.push(a);
        }
      }
    }
    else if(typeof mixed === 'object' && mixed !== null){
      for(var i in mixed){
        a = mixed[i];
        if(typeof a === 'object' && a !== null){
          return rec(a);
        }
        else{
          r.push(a);
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      r.push(mixed);
    }
    return r;
  }
  return rec(mixed);
}
var obj = {
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: [{
      name: 'parent',
      link: [{
        name: 'child1',
        link: [{
          name: 'child2',
          deepObj: {
            deepProp:'Number 7 test',
            num:7,
            deeperArray:[true, false, 'test', 'in', 'here', 1]
          }
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'parent2'
    }]
  }
}
var vals = getVals(obj);
// getVals returns an Array, hence the .join()
console.log(vals.join(', ')); console.log(vals);
```